# Python pandas "shift" to append rows beyond end of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and was wondering if there was a way to automatically append rows when using *shift*. So let's say I have a dataframe with 100 rows and three columns: a, b, and c.  'c' is an average of 'a' and 'b' shifted 30 rows.  The following line of code works well (note 'self' represents the dataframe and is used because I have my own class inherited from DataFrame):

```
self['c'] = ((self['a'] + self['b']) / 2).shift(30)
```

The above seems to work well but it stops at row 100 (the end of the dataframe). I need it to keep going to a row 130 (100 + the shifted 30).   Now I suppose I could have a *for loop* to append 30 rows to the dataframe before running the above, but as I learn pandas I am finding it does a lot of amazing stuff.  So I thought I would check to see if there was a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) your dataframe first to extend its range, else pandas won't know what to do with the extra rows. I assumed here that the index is a range, but you can easily adapt for other cases.

Here is a generic example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('ABCD'),
                   'col2': range(4)})
df = df.reindex(range(len(df)+3))
df['col2'] = df['col2'].shift(3)
```

Input:

```
  col1  col2
0    A     0
1    B     1
2    C     2
3    D     3
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2
0    A   NaN
1    B   NaN
2    C   NaN
3    D   0.0
4  NaN   1.0
5  NaN   2.0
6  NaN   3.0
```

Here is another example with a non range index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('ABCD'),
                   'col2': range(4)}, 
                  index=list('wxyz'))
df = df.reindex(list(df.index)+['new_%d'%i for i in range(3)])
df['col2'] = df['col2'].shift(3)
```

Output:

```
      col1  col2
w        A   NaN
x        B   NaN
y        C   NaN
z        D   0.0
new_0  NaN   1.0
new_1  NaN   2.0
new_2  NaN   3.0
```

*NB. There are several other ways to initially extend the dataframe (e.g., `append`, `concat`). Note that all options (including `reindex`) will create a new object.*

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with:

```
x = ([np.nan] * 30) + ((self['a'] + self['b']) / 2).tolist()
for i in range(30):
    self.loc[len(df) + i] = []
self['c'] = x.copy()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I added this block of code before my line of code and then after my line of code.  The results on both tests unfortunately don't expand the resultset beyond 100.