# Pandas Python Shift Data Past Last Date and Dataframe and Create/Append rows to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns (1) YoY % Change and (2) YoY Shifted. Column 2 is just column 1 shifted 4 periods forward using the following code:

```py
econ_data['YoY_Shifted'] = econ_data['YoY % Change'].shift(periods=4)
```

Dataframe:

| DATE | YoY % Change | YoY_Shifted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 3.440380 | 18.411664 |
| 2022-01-01 | 0.827626 | 15.579054 |
| 2022-04-01 | -1.656502 | 15.172007 |
| 2022-07-01 | -8.719386 | 7.633940 |
| 2022-10-01 | -14.081119 | 3.440380 |

The problem that I'm facing is that when I shift the data forward I'm missing the four latest data points because there are no dates for the next points. I could manually append four rows, but does anyone have a good solution as to how to automatically append the new corresponding dates after I shift forward?

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081218/python-pandas-shift-to-append-rows-beyond-end-of-dataframe), but it does not work with dates.

Comment: Are you trying to shift the entire dataframe down 4 rows, then fill in the dates column? I am struggling to understand what you mean by "does not work with dates"

Comment: Essentially when shift the dataframe, the newest 4 datapoints go away.

Comment: Once again really confusing. You are saying the "newest" datapoints but they don't exist? Can you provide an example of what the input and associated output should look like? And yes the 4 points got shifted down is that not what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Creating your Dataframe
econ_data = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2021-10-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-07-01',
                                                       '2022-10-01'], format='%Y-%m-%d'),
                               'YoY % Change': [3.440380, 0.827626, -1.656502, -8.719386, -14.081119],
                               'YoY Shifted': [18.411664, 15.579054, 15.172007, 7.633940, 3.440380]})

# Shifting the data as suggested.
econ_data = econ_data.reindex(range(len(econ_data) + 4))
econ_data['YoY Shifted'] = econ_data['YoY % Change'].shift(periods=4)

findnat = econ_data['Date'].isnull().idxmax()

for i in range(findnat, len(econ_data)):
    if pd.isnull(econ_data.at[i, 'Date']):
        econ_data.at[i, 'Date'] = econ_data.at[i-1, 'Date'] + pd.DateOffset(months=3)

print(econ_data)
============================================================================
OUTPUT:

        Date  YoY % Change  YoY Shifted
0 2021-10-01      3.440380          NaN
1 2022-01-01      0.827626          NaN
2 2022-04-01     -1.656502          NaN
3 2022-07-01     -8.719386          NaN
4 2022-10-01    -14.081119     3.440380
5 2023-01-01           NaN     0.827626
6 2023-04-01           NaN    -1.656502
7 2023-07-01           NaN    -8.719386
8 2023-10-01           NaN   -14.081119
```

Is this what you are looking for? There is most likely a way to achieve this without a loop although I am not well versed enough to figure it out. It should be easy to make the change necessary to make this reusable.

Comment: Let me know if you intended to keep the original contents of YoY Shifted 0 through 3