# Extending a column and moving rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe made of 5 rows and 2 columns. I need to shift the values of the second column two steps forward while maintaining the position of the first column, with nan in the empty places.

```
Original                               Expected
     A    B                             A    B
0    1    a                         0   1    nan
1    2    b                         1   2    nan
2    3    c                         2   3     a
3    4    d                         3   4     b
4    5    e                         4   5     c
                                    5  nan    d
                                    6  nan    e
```

How can I do that with pandas ? The dataframe is juste an example.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081218/python-pandas-shift-to-append-rows-beyond-end-of-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B':list('abcde')})
```

**Code**

reindex & shift

```
n = 2
out = df.reindex(pd.RangeIndex(len(df) + n)).assign(B=lambda x: x['B'].shift(n))
```

out

```
    A   B
0   1.0 None
1   2.0 None
2   3.0 a
3   4.0 b
4   5.0 c
5   NaN d
6   NaN e
```

you can change `n`.

you can use this code, when original df have RangeIndex like your example

Comment: You can also replace `pd.RangeIndex(len(df) + n)` with `df.index + n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can first append two (or whatever number of rows you're shifting by) empty rows to your dataframe and use the [shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function.

```
df.loc[len(df)] = None
df.loc[len(df)] = None

     A    B
0    1    a
1    2    b
2    3    c
3    4    d
4    5    e
5  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  NaN
```

Then you can shift the column by two rows :

```
df['B'] = df['B'].shift(2, fill_value=np.nan)

     A    B
0    1  NaN
1    2  NaN
2    3    a
3    4    b
4    5    c
5  NaN    d
6  NaN    e
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
>>> pd.concat([df['A'], df['B'].set_axis(df.index+2)], axis=1)
     A    B
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN
2  3.0    a
3  4.0    b
4  5.0    c
5  NaN    d
6  NaN    e
```

If your index is not numeric, you can use [`np.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.pad(df['A'].astype(float), (2, 0), constant_values=np.nan)
B = np.pad(df['B'], (0, 2), constant_values=np.nan)
out = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
n = 2
pd.DataFrame({
    'A': df['A'].to_list() + [np.nan]*n,
    'B': [np.nan]*n + df['B'].to_list()})
```

Output:

```
     A    B
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN
2  3.0    a
3  4.0    b
4  5.0    c
5  NaN    d
6  NaN    e
```